# Stop execution of a function if layout is mdpi/ldpi?

Tags: android, android-layout, mdpi

I am designing an Android application and I am struggling with different layouts. Basically, I am showing a Calendar and a TextView when on portrait, which updates its value each time a tile from the calendar is clicked. I don't want the TextView to show up anymore in land-mdpi. I created a layout for landscape, mdpi, in which I deleted the TextView option, but I think I have to do this programatically, as an error appears now every time I try to click a tile on a device with such specifications (the function is still active and tries to update the TextView - which does not exist anymore in this layout format). How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get the `TextView` reference from your view hierarchy using `findViewById()`, you'll get a `null` if the view is not there. So just use something along the lines of

```
TextView tv = (TextView)someView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
if (tv != null) {
  // The TextView is there and can be used
} else {
  // The TextView isn't there
}
```